# sqlAlchemy: session.query(Model.column) returns false

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Using sqlalchemy to query a table that is self-referencing as below -

```
district = session.query(
    District._id, District.name, District.level,
    District.parent, District.ordering, District.description,
    functions.ST_AsGeoJSON(District.area).label('area'),....
    ,.... and some columns

).filter(
    st_contains(
        'district.area',
        st_point(lat, lng)
    )
).filter(
    District.level == float(level)
).first()
```

The query executes properly, but for column District.parent, **False** is returned instead of the parent id.

Below is the Model Class for District

```
class District(Base):
__tablename__ = 'district'
_id = Column('_id', Text, primary_key=True)
_database_id = Column('_database_id', Text, primary_key=True)
_owner_id = Column('_owner_id', Text, primary_key=True)
_created_by = Column('_created_by', Text)
_updated_by = Column('_updated_by', Text)
_access = Column('_access', JSON)
_created_at = Column('_created_at', DateTime)
_updated_at = Column('_updated_at', DateTime)
name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
level = Column(DOUBLE_PRECISION, nullable=False)
parent_id = Column(
    'parent',
    Text,
    ForeignKey('district._id'),
)
parent = relationship(
    'District',
    foreign_keys='District.parent_id',
)
```

If i print the query i get something like this -

```
SELECT district._id AS district__id, district.name AS district_name, 
district.level AS district_level, district._id = district.parent AS parent, 
district.ordering AS district_ordering, district.description AS 
district_description, ST_AsGeoJSON(district.area) AS area...,......
FROM district
WHERE ST_contains(area, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(22.2883291, 
114.14048449999996),4326)) AND district.level = %(level_1)s
LIMIT %(param_1)s
```

For parent field it gives something strange -> district._id = district.parent AS parent

Can someone highlight what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What is `district_alias` that appears in your sqlalchemy sentence. It seems that it must be `District.parent` instead

Comment: Sorry, i've edited the question. It was District.parent. My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `District` class definition, `parent` it is not a `Column`, it is a `relationship`. So to get the `_id` of the parent you must use:

```
district = session.query(
    District._id, District.name, District.level,
    District.parent_id, ...
)
```